# Try out wayland on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: gnome, live-usb, wayland

I downloaded the Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 image to try it out via live stick. Once in the live system I installed the Wayland support via

```
apt install gnome-session-wayland
```

After logging out of the live sysyem there is no option to start Gnome live using Wayland.

NOT using NVidia - Integrated Intel graphics.

Is there a way to try out Gnome 3 with Wayland support on a live system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Comment: Additional information: the live USB stick will "forget" anything installed on it after reboot.  The easy way would be to install from one USB stick to another and then you have a fully persistent Ubuntu install in which you can do anything including nVidia and Wayland installs.

Answer (score 0):

At the login prompt (the LightDM Greeter), there is a small icon that changes based upon what the current default shell is set to be, such as the Ubuntu Unity triskelion or the GNOME footprint. If you click that icon, you get a pull-down list of installed desktop shell environments to choose from.

As an aside, I haven't had good results with GNOME on Wayland as it seems highly dependent upon hardware compatibilty, so if it works then more power to you.

Comment: Does this work without actually installing Ubuntu? I am asking to try out Ubuntu Gnome Wayland using the Live Image.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to try Wayland on a Live USB of Ubuntu 17.10 here how you can do it.

1. Log out from the default session you get automatically logged in
2. Open a "real" terminal (a non emulated one) using `CTRL + ALT + F6`and login as user **ubuntu**
3. Stop GDM3 `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop`
4. Change GDM3 configurations by editing `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

   > WaylandEnable=true
   >
   > AutomaticLoginEnable = false
5. Restart GDM3 `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 start`
6. Go back to graphical interface `CTRL + ALT + F1`
7. Login
8. Have Fun

Source
http://www.bernaschina.com/en/blog/try-wayland-ubuntu-1710-live-usb/