# Laptop keyboard not working when trying to install Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, iso, 23.10

Today I have acquired a new laptop, Maibenben X565, with preinstalled Kubuntu based on Ubuntu 22.10. I downloaded an ISO image of the regular Ubuntu 23.10 from the official site, created an ISO image on a USB, rebooted the system and then tried to install Ubuntu 23.10 using live USB. The keyboard works just fine with the preinstalled Kubuntu or in the BIOS menu, but stops working when I launch "try to install Ubuntu".

**EDIT:**
First, my laptop does not have a touch screen. It does not have an fn button to disable the keyboard. The menu "Keyboard" in Ubuntu Settings does not contain any information on the keyboard or on lack of thereof. Using screen keyboard, I ran `sudo lshw` upon launching live USB with Ubuntu 23.10, and the keyboard is not listed in the list of input devices (while the touchpad is). In `/dev/input/by-path`, there is no folder for keyboard. The command

```bash
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type
```

suggested in an answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274890/ubuntu-20-04-keyboard-not-working) post, returns 10. However, I am not sure if it solves the problem, for once, because the bug described there appears to be at least 3 years old, and its unlikely that it hasn't been fixed yet (a comment in the linked posts suggests the bug was fixed already in the kernel version 5.4, and the current kernel version is 6.something). Another reason is that the solution there suggests you should reboot the system, but for me, this bug occurs already when launching the system from the live boot USB, meaning, in order to apply the solution there, I would need to first install the new Ubuntu, and for that I either need to destroy the current Kubuntu 22.10 build, in which at least the keyboard works, or to partition the hard drive and install Ubuntu 23.10 alongside with Kubuntu 22.10, when try to fix the bug, and then reinstall the whole system again if the fix works, so this will only be my last resort if nothing else works.

Besides, the recommendation there is not applicable to my case anyway, because I have AMD CPU, not Intel, and so I doubt blacklisting `intel_vbtn` could help.

**EDIT 2:** Eventually I have tried the only solution proposed under the suggested [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274890/ubuntu-20-04-keyboard-not-working) that was at least possible to perform in my situation, namely, I installed Ubuntu using the screen keyboard and then blacklisted `intel_vbtn`. I don't have dual boot Windows, I don't have slow keys mode activated, my keyboard is not a detachable USB device, my kernel version is higher than 5.20, and my laptop is not even aware that its built-in keypad **exists**, it does not **disable** it recieving a signal of touchscreen activation or something. `sudo libinput debug-events` does not detect any `SW_TABLET_MODE` events. In fact, I am suspicious that somehow the keyboard is recognized as a Video Bus, since two Video Buses are detected for some reason.

**EDIT 3:**
Here is the result of running `sudo lshw -businfo`:

```
Bus info          Device          Class          Description
============================================================
                                  system         Typhoon Series (X565)
                                  bus            X565
                                  memory         64KiB BIOS
                                  memory         384KiB L1 cache
                                  memory         3MiB L2 cache
                                  memory         16MiB L3 cache
cpu@0                             processor      AMD Ryzen 5 6600H with Radeon Graphics
                                  memory         16GiB System Memory
                                  memory         8GiB SODIMM Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 4800 MHz (0.2 ns)
                                  memory         8GiB SODIMM Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 4800 MHz (0.2 ns)
pci@0000:00:00.0                  bridge         Family 17h-19h PCIe Root Complex
pci@0000:00:00.2                  generic        Family 17h-19h IOMMU
pci@0000:00:01.1                  bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
pci@0000:01:00.0                  display        GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]
pci@0000:01:00.1  card0           multimedia     NVIDIA Corporation
                  input10         input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
                  input11         input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
                  input8          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                  input9          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
pci@0000:00:02.1                  bridge         Family 17h-19h PCIe GPP Bridge
pci@0000:02:00.0  eno1            network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
pci@0000:00:02.2                  bridge         Family 17h-19h PCIe GPP Bridge
pci@0000:03:00.0  wlp3s0          network        MT7921K (RZ608) Wi-Fi 6E 80MHz
pci@0000:00:02.4                  bridge         Family 17h-19h PCIe GPP Bridge
pci@0000:04:00.0  /dev/nvme0      storage        YMTC PC300-512GB-B
                  hwmon3          disk           NVMe disk
                  /dev/ng0n1      disk           NVMe disk
nvme@0:1          /dev/nvme0n1    disk           512GB NVMe disk
nvme@0:1,1        /dev/nvme0n1p1  volume         1074MiB Windows FAT volume
nvme@0:1,2        /dev/nvme0n1p2  volume         475GiB EXT4 volume
pci@0000:00:08.1                  bridge         Family 17h-19h Internal PCIe GPP Bridge
pci@0000:05:00.0                  display        Rembrandt [Radeon 680M]
pci@0000:05:00.2                  generic        VanGogh PSP/CCP
pci@0000:05:00.3                  bus            Rembrandt USB4 XHCI controller #3
usb@1             usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
usb@1:3                           multimedia     HD Webcam
usb@2             usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
pci@0000:05:00.4                  bus            Rembrandt USB4 XHCI controller #4
usb@3             usb3            bus            xHCI Host Controller
usb@3:3                           communication  Wireless_Device
usb@4             usb4            bus            xHCI Host Controller
pci@0000:05:00.5                  multimedia     ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor
pci@0000:05:00.6  card1           multimedia     Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
                  input12         input          HD-Audio Generic Mic
                  input13         input          HD-Audio Generic Headphone
pci@0000:00:08.3                  bridge         Family 17h-19h Internal PCIe GPP Bridge
pci@0000:06:00.0                  bus            Rembrandt USB4 XHCI controller #8
usb@5             usb5            bus            xHCI Host Controller
usb@5:1                           bus            Hub
usb@6             usb6            bus            xHCI Host Controller
pci@0000:06:00.3                  bus            Rembrandt USB4 XHCI controller #5
usb@7             usb7            bus            xHCI Host Controller
usb@8             usb8            bus            xHCI Host Controller
pci@0000:06:00.4                  bus            Rembrandt USB4 XHCI controller #6
usb@9             usb9            bus            xHCI Host Controller
usb@10            usb10           bus            xHCI Host Controller
pci@0000:00:14.0                  bus            FCH SMBus Controller
pci@0000:00:14.3                  bridge         FCH LPC Bridge
                                  system         PnP device PNP0c01
                                  system         PnP device PNP0b00
                                  input          PnP device PNP0303
                                  system         PnP device PNP0c02
pci@0000:00:01.0                  bridge         Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
pci@0000:00:02.0                  bridge         Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
pci@0000:00:03.0                  bridge         Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
pci@0000:00:04.0                  bridge         Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
pci@0000:00:08.0                  bridge         Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
pci@0000:00:18.0                  bridge         Rembrandt Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
pci@0000:00:18.1                  bridge         Rembrandt Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
pci@0000:00:18.2                  bridge         Rembrandt Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
pci@0000:00:18.3                  bridge         Rembrandt Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
pci@0000:00:18.4                  bridge         Rembrandt Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
pci@0000:00:18.5                  bridge         Rembrandt Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
pci@0000:00:18.6                  bridge         Rembrandt Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
pci@0000:00:18.7                  bridge         Rembrandt Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
                  /dev/fb0        display        EFI VGA
                  input0          input          Power Button
                  input1          input          Sleep Button
                  input14         input          UNIW0001:00 093A:0255 Mouse
                  input15         input          UNIW0001:00 093A:0255 Touchpad
                  input16         input          Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard
                  input2          input          Lid Switch
                  input6          input          Video Bus
                  input7          input          Video Bus
```

The Bluetooth keyboard is an external device used instead of the built-in keyboard.

**EDIT 4:**
I also tried the thing described [here](https://stevesubuntutweaks.blogspot.com/2013/10/laptop-keyboard-stopped-working-after.html), namely changing a line in `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1"`, then running `sudo update-grub` and restarting. Also didn't help. Also, my installation of Ubuntu uses x11, not Wayland.

Comment: Is there a fn button to disable the keyboard? You may need to toggle this. Otherwise, go into the system settings and then look up the input options and keyboard options and see what it says (edit your question and include this info if it's not apparently clear). One thing I can think of is that sometimes it might switch off the keyboard if the laptop has touchscreen, thinking that you should be using an on screen keyboard instead, or something along those lines.

Comment: Also, check to see if any of [these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274890/ubuntu-20-04-keyboard-not-working) fixes your issue.

Comment: My laptop does not have a touchscreen. I will certainly review the answers suggested in the post you have linked and update the question accordingly.

Comment: I have tried everything proposed there; to no avail. The laptop simply does not recognize the existence of its internal keyboard. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: If the old version uses x11 instead of wayland, that might be the issue. So maybe try using x11 instead. I think you can try basically doing the opposite of what is [described in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1268028). So if the following line exists: `#WaylandEnable=false` then change the line to `WaylandEnable=false` (uncomment the line). If the line `WaylandEnable=true` exists, then change the line to `WaylandEnable=false`. If none of those lines exist, then add the following line `WaylandEnable=false` to the file and then proceed with the rest of the instructions.

Comment: The __new__ version already uses x11, as indicated by the check described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202891/how-to-know-whether-wayland-or-x11-is-being-used)